# Get a specific number from a very long string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I write a python program to find all the consecutive numbers of pi with a million digits in a txt file by Python?

eg, if I want to find all the six-digit consecutive numbers, I can run the program and output might show
`['123456', '234567'.....]` are exist

if I want to find all the three-digit consecutive numbers, the output might show
`['123', '234'.....]` are exist

Comment: Please add a more detailed example to explain exactly what you mean. It might also help to add some code to show what you've tried so far, even if it's just a rough attempt / idea.

Comment: I have opened a txt file containing million digit in python and it is now a string containing million of digit. I want to find all the seven-digit consecutive numbers within this string.

Comment: @goxywood So, does this text have one single string of millions of digits or there are any separators between them, like a white space? Can you display a snapshot of this text file?

Comment: @a_r I have elinminated all the space. It is now ' '3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820......' milion of digit in python. It is now one single string

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun(n, piList):
l = []
for i in range(len(piList)):
    subset = piList[i:i+n]
    sortedSubset = sorted(subset)
    firstOfSubset = sortedSubset[0]
    targetSubset = list(range(firstOfSubset,firstOfSubset+n))
    if subset == targetSubset:
        l.append(subset)
    if len(piList) - (i + n) ==0:
        break

return l
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def fun(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        subset = nums[i:i+n]
        if subset == sorted(subset):
            l.append(subset)

    return l
```

Comment: you should not try to build the whole list right away, it's too big and likely overflow the memory and take a lot of time to get built. try returning elements one-by-one, when they are really needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
>>> a = '12345564564'
>>> def get_nums( nums, length ) :
...     for i in range(len(nums)) :
...         selection = nums[i:i+length]
...         if len(selection) < length : break
...         yield selection

>>> for n in get_nums( a, 6 ) : print n
... 
123455
234556
345564
455645
556456
564564
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas. I have solved this problem.

My method is using two for loops first to creat a consecutive number list, eg. ['0123456', '1234567', '2343456',......, '9012345']

Then I check 'if' any of the above list items is excisting 'in' the long pi and append the existing list item to a empty list and finally print it.

Thanks!